# enable dynamic textbox for checking dynamic checkbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls

Here i am creating a textbox and its corresponding checkbox. what i need is... i want to enable the textbox when i check the checkbox
Note: textbox is initially disabled

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            TextBox txt_ele = new TextBox();

            txt_ele.ID = "elective" + i;
            txt_ele.Enabled = false;

            chk.ID = "chk_" + i.ToString();
            chk.Text = "Has Elective Subjects";
            chk.AutoPostBack = true;

            cell.Controls.Add(chk);
            cell.Controls.Add(txt_ele);

            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            chk.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler (chkDynamic_CheckedChanged);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        this.NumberOfControls++;
    }
```

page.Form.Controls.Add(table);

and check box checked event is as follows

```
protected void chkDynamic_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox lb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (lb.Checked)
    {
          //how to do here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
protected void chkDynamic_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox lb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (lb.Checked)
    {
        (Page.FindControlRecursive(
            "elective" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
                lb.ID, 
                @"(\d+)(?!.*\d)").ToString()) 
            as System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl)
        .Enabled = true;
    }
}

public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
    {
        return Root;
    }

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
        if (FoundCtl != null)
        {
            return FoundCtl;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is matching the numeric part of the checkbox id and then using it to create the textbox id. Using FindControl to retrieve the control and then enabling it.

Comment: In your chkDynamic_CheckedChanged  event

Comment: I've just added an @ sign before the Regex; try that

Comment: I've added another method for finding the control in case there is an issue there, but seeing as you're not getting any errors, it seems that the control must be being found and this probably won't get you any further. I tested the above code my end and it works fine for me.

Comment: m getting following error :  Compiler Error Message: CS1106: Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic (without postback) you'll be needing to use AJAX (UpdatePanel) on your aspx page or jQuery, at least its easier that way

Comment: ajax is post back but it doesn't refresh the whole page. and he didn't say he doesn't want post back

Answer (score 0):

this is a very dirty solution but its for you to pick it up and make it a production solution:

```
protected void chkDynamic_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox lb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (lb.Checked)
    {
        ((TextBox)lb.Parent.FindControl("elective" + lb.ID.Replace("chk_", string.Empty))).Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: does the check box post back? 
when you hit the handler does it execute ok or are there any exceptions?